# Encryption and decryption with AES PKCS7Padding Fails

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am trying to create Encryption and decryption functions with AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding.

```
private static byte[] INITIALIZATION_VECTOR = new byte[] { 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 };
public static String encrypt(String token) {
    Cipher cipher = null;
    SecretKey key = null;
    String tokenAsHex = null;
    byte[] encryptedToken = null;
    byte[] sksKey = "6iOmT2V6mnd0".getBytes(); // SecretKeySpec key.

    try {
        key = new SecretKeySpec(sksKey, "AES");
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(INITIALIZATION_VECTOR);
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); 
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        encryptedToken = cipher.doFinal(token.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedToken);
}

public static String decrypt(String token) {
    Cipher cipher = null;
    SecretKey key = null;
    byte[] decryptedToken = null;
    byte[] sksKey = "6iOmT2V6mnd0".getBytes(); // SecretKeySpec key.
    try {
        key = new SecretKeySpec(sksKey, "AES");            
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(INITIALIZATION_VECTOR);
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); 
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        decryptedToken = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(token));
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
    if (decryptedToken == null) {
         System.out.println("Unable to decrypt the following token: " + token);
    }
    return new String(decryptedToken);
}
```

I have edited my program.

now the dycryption seems to work, but it only works with PKCS5Padding , when i try to use PKCS7Padding it says it cannot find provider , how can it be?

Comment: please use something like google's keyczar library instead.  it's easier to use and you're much more likely to get secure code.

Comment: PKCS#5 and PKCS#7 padding are effectively the same.  Some systems use one name, while other systems use the other.  In your case the default provider uses the `PKCS5` name.  Basically, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

You have several mistakes:

1. Don't convert ciphertext to a string - this is likely to be a lossy conversion. Instead, keep it as a byte array or convert it to hexadecimal or base64.
2. You need to store the IV for use during decryption. Currently you just throw it away (in your `enc` method). A common technique is to prefix the ciphertext with your IV (possibly separated by a delimiter).
3. When you create a string from your decrypted bytes, you should specify a charset.

This might not be an exhaustive list, but it's certainly enough to cause you major problems. Fix these and then let us know if you are still seeing errors (and *post the errors in your question*).

*Also, returning a string with `"error"` is poor design. In Java, use exceptions to indicate something has gone wrong.*

Comment: fixed most of the issues, but  when i try to use PKCS7Padding it says it cannot find provider , do you know why is that?

Comment: @susparsy Most providers call it `PKCS5Padding`. It's essentially [the same thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#PKCS7).